# Cannot open SQL Server Log file

Tags: ssms

I cannot open the SQL Server error log file from Management>SQL Server Logs.  I get the following message when I double click 'SQL Server Logs':

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc) For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: An exception occurred while executing a
>   Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
>   should be discarded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0) For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476

This happens from SSMS running on the client or the server.  The actual error log files do exist and are referenced correctly with the startup -e parameter.  I can open the error logs manually with Windows Explorer/Notepad.  At the same time I try to view the log, this error message appears in the Windows Application Log

Severity: 16 Error:18456, OS: 18456 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'LOCAL-SERVER-NAME\SQLService_EI_SQL'.

I have no idea what the issue is, but I would like to be able to view the SQL logs from within SSMS.  I gave the local service account full permissions on the Log folder.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and added my service account as a windows authenticated login within SQL server, granting it the sysadmin role and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error (Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc))
and solved by Installing the latest ODBC driver that support SQL server version.

Comment: It will be great if you could help to update the ODBC driver.